# How can I test google functions framework environment variables before deploy?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to set up environment variables for GCF (node version) and I am following the guide here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#setting_runtime_environment_variables

According to these docs, the steps to add environment variables all require a deploy step, e.g. `gcloud functions deploy <FUNCTION_NAME> --env-vars-file .env.yaml <FLAGS>`. This is non-intuitive to me, since I need to test my changes locally first to ensure they work *before* I deploy them. Am I missing something here, or is there simply a moment where the framework violates the principle of least surprise?

I tried running the local function using `npx functions-framework --env-vars-file .env-dev.yaml` but the `env-vars-file` option appears to be ignored in this context. I also tried using dotenv-yaml but I'm not sure how to set this up in combination with `npx functions-framework`.

A clunky workaround is available... but I'd prefer not to do something for dev such as `FOO=bar npx functions-framework` for local dev only. It would be much more manageable with a lot of variables to just have two identically structured yaml files, one for dev and one for prod. It would also be less error-prone.

TLDR: Google Cloud function wants me to keep env vars in yaml, so how do I test them locally with my node function before I deploy them?

Comment: Create a script that reads your YAML env file or duplicates its values. The key item is that you must set the shell's environment variables. This is a common paradox in development. Develop the strategy you like as there is no common solution.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the useful and practical suggestion from John Hanley, this workaround is acceptable for my purposes. It can probably refactored, but it does the job for now. If the functions framework ever supports a yaml env file (for node runtimes) during the run step then this won't be necessary. According to Google's docs this would also potentially be unnecessary if using [buildpacks or containers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/overview), which we currently do not.

package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
   "dev": "env MY_PROJECT_ENV=dev npx functions-framework"
},
...
```

constants.js:

```js
const ENV = process.env.AI_LABS_ENV || 'prod'

let envVars = {}
if (ENV === 'dev') {
  // import asynchronously so unnecessary imports do not occur in production
  const yaml = await import('js-yaml')
  const fs = await import('fs')
  const path = await import('path')
  try {
    envVars = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('.env-dev.yaml'), 'utf8'))
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error attempting to load .env-dev.yaml. Does the file exist in the root directory?')
    console.log(e)
  }
} else {
  envVars = process.env
}

const MY_VAR = envVars.MY_VAR
```

Comment: Very easy to understand solution.